# Compare a number against multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table refill_roster having 3 timeslots for each day

```
mysql> select day,slot1,slot2,slot3 from location_refill_roster;
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| day  | slot1    | slot2    | slot3    |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|    1 | 14:45:22 | 14:45:24 | 14:45:25 |
|    2 | 14:45:22 | 14:45:24 | 14:45:25 |
|    3 | 14:45:22 | 14:45:24 | 14:45:25 |
|    4 | 14:45:22 | 14:45:24 | 14:45:25 |
|    5 | 14:45:22 | 14:45:34 | 14:45:25 |
|    6 | 14:45:22 | 14:45:24 | 14:45:25 |
|    7 | 09:45:22 | 11:45:28 | 12:45:25 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to find at certain point in time what is the next timeslot for that day.For example in day 7 at 10:00:00 next available slot should be slot2 i.e 11:45:28.

Couldn't find a way to compare a number against multiple column. So i transposed the table and wrote a subquery to compare. Is there any better way to achieve the solution

```
SELECT slots,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day = '1' THEN value END) `1`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day = '2' THEN value END) `2`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day = '3' THEN value END) `3`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day = '4' THEN value END) `4`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day = '5' THEN value END) `5`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day = '6' THEN value END) `6`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN day = '7' THEN value END) `7`
FROM
(
 SELECT day, slots,
     CASE slots 
        WHEN 'slot1' THEN slot1
        WHEN 'slot2' THEN slot2
        WHEN 'slot3' THEN slot3
     END value
FROM refill_roster t CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'slot1' slots UNION ALL
    SELECT 'slot2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'slot3' 
  ) c where t.day=7
) q 
 GROUP BY slots
 ORDER BY FIELD(slots, 'slot1', 'slot2', 'slot3')
```

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: you shoudl normalize your slots structure  ..

Comment: @Strawberry design depends on the requirement and it has other columns that i omitted to simplify the question.

Comment: It makes no difference. A normalised design is the key to this

Comment: aside from poor structure, can you provide context this query is trying to provide.  Your data for days 1-6 could imply that SLOT 1 should be returned for days 1-6 since the first slot is after the 10am sample you are looking for and slot 2 for day 7.  As Strawberry has mentioned, a better structure might be a better avenue, but without the other context that you are not showing of a bigger picture, assume it must be left as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a MySQL user, but this is how I'd approach it.  I'm sure others can correct me if I'm proposing something MySQL can't do.

I assume the day (1-7) is a parameter, so I'll call it `@day`.  I'm also assuming the time you want to compare to is a time, `@currentTime`.

I am also assuming that `slot1 <= slot2 <= slot3`.  If this isn't always true, then this would get more complicated.

```
 select  case when @currentTime <= slot1 then slot1
              when @currentTime <= slot2 then slot2
              when @currentTime <= slot3 then slot3
              else null
         end as [NextSlot]
 from    refill_roster rr
 where   rr.day = @day
```

Comment: It's not that it's something you can't do. It just that it's a bad idea (regardless of RDBMS), as compared with the alternative, i.e. fixing the schema design.

Comment: Also, we know that the assertion `slot1 <= slot2 <= slot3` is false.

Comment: @Strawberry Agreed, but people often have to work in databases whose schemas they don't have the power to change, such as databases for software packages.  I'm assuming the OP is in such a situation.

Comment: I think that's unnecessarily presumptuous!

Comment: @Strawberry Because of that one value for day 5, slot 2?  Fair enough.

Comment: @Strawberry Well, you've given the OP your advice: he or she is free to learn from it.  And, please note, I *agree with you* that the design is poor and that it would be better to fix it (if they can) than try to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(day INT NOT NULL
,slot INT NOT NULL
,time TIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(day,slot)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'14:45:22'),
(2,1,'14:45:22'),
(3,1,'14:45:22'),
(4,1,'14:45:22'),
(5,1,'14:45:22'),
(6,1,'14:45:22'),
(7,1,'09:45:22'),
(1,2,'14:45:24'),
(2,2,'14:45:24'),
(3,2,'14:45:24'),
(4,2,'14:45:24'),
(5,2,'14:45:34'),
(6,2,'14:45:24'),
(7,2,'11:45:28'),
(1,3,'14:45:25'),
(2,3,'14:45:25'),
(3,3,'14:45:25'),
(4,3,'14:45:25'),
(5,3,'14:45:25'),
(6,3,'14:45:25'),
(7,3,'12:45:25');

SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE day = 7 
   AND time > '10:00:00' 
 ORDER 
    BY slot 
 LIMIT 1;

  +-----+------+----------+
  | day | slot | time     |
  +-----+------+----------+
  |   7 |    2 | 11:45:28 |
  +-----+------+----------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: After transposing the table it is fairly easy, but how would you achieve it without transposing from original table

Comment: I wouldn't even bother trying.